# Rails database migration fails with "duplicate column name: email" when adding devise's generated User table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, database-migration

I am in the process of installing `devise`. I followed all the required steps and ended here:

```
$ rails generate devise User
$ rake db:migrate
```

When I run `rake db:migrate` I get the following error:

```
$ rake db:migrate
== 20140618020442 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "em
ail" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULLc:/appname/db/migrate/20140618020442_add_d
evise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
c:/appname/db/migrate/20140618020442_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
c:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My project has the following database schema. Some of the `devise` migration appears to be successful, but the migration was not completed.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140618020442) do

  create_table "listings", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Looks like you have already created the column `email` on your `user` table. You could go to the Devise migration file remove the `t.string :email` line then run `rake db:migrate` again.

Comment: I removed the t.string :email line. When I now run rake db:migrate it gives me the same error just with the t.string :encrypted_password line. When I delete this one it goes on to the next line and so on...

Comment: @user3208597 can you list all the steps you did?

Comment: @user2675613 do you mean removing the lines and run db:migrate or do you mean what I did before?

Comment: @user3208597 i meant what all steps you did you install devise? and can you post your migration file `timestamp_devise_create_users.rb` and also your `schema.rb` file just to check if there's already a users table

Comment: @user2675613 I think you found the problem. Please see above my schema.rb file. Do I delete or comment out these lines that are double?

Comment: @user3208597 Looks like you already have the users table in your database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem is you already have the users table inside your database. You need to either drop that table and create a new one if it's not working or just continue using that table.

It's not a good idea to drop your database but since you are making a new app(as you creating a users table) so in your case it'll be better to drop that database and recreate it(to make sure everything works). Try these commands in sequence:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

It should work fine and you **need not** do `rails generate devise User` as you already have your users migration file

**Update:**

If you don't want to drop your database then you can create a new migration file and delete your users table there.

```
rails generate migration DropUsersTable
```

after that edit your migration file

```
class DropUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

and then do `rake db:migrate`

Comment: You don't necessarily know this app is new. Who says that the first step in app development is creating the `users` table? There are solutions *around* having to entirely drop your database and all the data associated with it. Maybe his only table is `listings`, but he might have thousands of columns in that table. Prepare for the worst, assume the best. Give him the answer that would solve the solution given he can't drop his entire data set. (Yes, I like how you mentioned in your answer about how it's not a good idea to drop DB...I thought you should've continued in that direction :) )

Comment: @Justin if you read his question "properly" he is following a tutorial which means he is just starting to learn it and if you would have "cared enough" and opened the tutorial link he has provided you would have seen that he has just started to add his application. I knew there would be some "folks" like you that's why i clearly mentioned in my answer that it's not a good practice and if you would have noticed i have also specified that in order to be sure that your app gets up and running you can recreate your databse

Comment: @Justin I suggested it just to make sure that his app is up and running as soon as possible cuz i have also gone through that phase and no one likes to struck up not specially when you are just starting it up

Comment: I went to baserails.com and saw something where it costs money to (albeit first a free trial), but nonetheless something that required CC. I would hope you can understand my comment and reasoning for it though. Apologies for offending you.

Comment: @Justin there's a how it works section too where you could check it. I can edit my answer and change it but you know what's the funny thing, instead of "answering his question" you opted to just look at it and down voted an answer which has stated all the downsides

Comment: Hello everyone. So I did the following: I followed @user2675613 Update and created drop_user table and edited it. Than I ran: rake db:migrate. I get the following error:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: DROP TABLE "users"c:/appname/db/mi
grate/20140618162921_drop_users_table.rb:3:in `change'
c:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Did I do it in the wrong order?

Comment: @user3208597 i hope you didn't drop your database according to my earlier answer and then create a migration to drop that table again

Comment: @user2675613 No I did not

Comment: @user3208597 Just to check if user table exist or not can you go in your app directory in terminal and do `rails c` and then write `User`. If you have users table then it will list all its columns. Do you see any error?

Comment: I am not exactly sure if I did it right I tried two things:
$ rails c
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.1)
irb(main):001:0> User
irb(main):002:0*
Then I do not know what to enter next

Comment: and

$ rails c User
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb fil
es accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test enviro
nment)
  * production - set it to true
and a whole bunch of other lines starting with lib

Comment: @user3208597 You didn't get any output after writing User and hitting enter?

Comment: @user3208597 ok for some reason rails console is not working in your app and it's showing deprecation(may be its rails 4.1). Open your schema.rb file and check for creating users table and after that is there already a command to drop users table?

Comment: @user3208597 your error says that you don't have a users table. Don't give up on it now. Tell me is there a create users and a drop users inside your schema.rb file

Comment: @user2675613 there is a users table in the schema.rb. There is nothing that says drop. I'll post the updated schema.rb above

Comment: Okay I found a solution please see above

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
1.  Put all the migrations in migration folder in new archived_migrations folder.
2.  db:schema:load
3.      Run rake db:migrate

Comment: Why are you putting all the migrations in a single file? In a real project you won't be able to do that and it's same as recreating your database again may be even worse :)

Comment: The migration files were in single file from the beginning in "migrate". I forgot to mention that I also ran rake db:schema:load. This solved the issue for me and did not create a new database. Could you explain the problem with this further?

Comment: Migration files are always in a single migrate folder. You said you put them all in a single file and then ran that migration file that's what I'm talking about. In a real project you don't know all your requirements and you already have a database filled with data

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant that I put them all in one folder. 
Sorry for the confusion and thank you so much for all the effort you put into solving my problem. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

### Rails database migration fails with "duplicate column name

if you get above error its because you have a duplicate .rb file in db/migrate folder
just delete it and job done!!